# Setting a Network location in Java ClassPath

Tags: java, classpath

I am trying to run a Java Program on Windows machines. Libraries for program are placed on a network location - `\\libs\myprog`. **I can't create a network drive on my windows machine**.

Now question is, how to set Java Classpath for above lib?

I tried following:

```
java -cp \\libs\myprog Main

java -cp //libs/myprog Main
```

But nothing worked.

Comment: This is a really bad idea in the first place, regardless of whether you can make it work. Programs shouldn't criticall rely on network resources.

Comment: @EJP Yes, you are right and in fact I never had to use it. But this is a business use case, so helpless!!

Comment: That remote folder needs to be defined as a local one in your system. Because classpath resources are being read like they are all in local so java needs an inputStream. In order to do that, that folder needs to be defined as a local folder.

Comment: @Neron I also feel same, but was looking if somehow is it possible to achieve this.

Comment: System should know that , it can access that file like other local files. If not, network protocols will be involved and it will not work. For unix, check this:  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-creating-symbolic-link-ln-command/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do anything special (I checked it with Java 7).

My program was not working because there was some typo. So, if I have to add a jars from a network path

`\\remote\libs` to my program's classpath, then all I need is to fire following command:

```
java -cp local.jar;\\remote\libs\*;. MAIN
```

That is all!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are desparate and you really need this (beware: it is lousy from design and performance point of view), you can use a `URLClassLoader` for retrieving those libraries at runtime. 
Just configure the URLs you want to load the libs from e.g. at application start at argument to the main class or as System property and hand them over to a URLClassLoader which then can retrieve the classes (probably a lot slower and more risky then local file system access, but it will work).
Have a look at the Javadoc: [URLClassLoader javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html)

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can complete your work by "java -javaagent:**.jar=option -jar your.jar".

Just as far as i know, you can load Class using URLClassLoader etc from the remote server in agent Class.

But, it maybe work, because i just coded agent application.